# Webview refresh on chromebook maximize/minimize

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I have a webview in my Android app. I navigate to some other page in the same webview. I press F4, that is the fullscreen button on Asus Chromebook. The webview reloads and comes back to the first page.

I have tried adding,

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

to my activity in the manifest. But the issue still remains.

Webview is inside a fragment, if that matters. 
I also have

```
setRetainInstance(true)
```

in my fragment to retain WebView state.

I am guessing maximizing and minimizing Chromebook windows is not same as orientation changes on normal tablets. Because I have locked my orientation to portrait and tested it on tablets and do not see the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

So looks like I was testing on a Chromebook with Android 6.0 built in.
And for 6.0 from the Android Developers website,

```
These apps are treated as unsafe to be resized. If possible, these apps launch by default to a phone-sized portrait window; otherwise they launch into a phone-sized landscape window. 
The user can press F4 to enter or leave full screen mode which fully restarts the app—killing and starting the app anew—and keeps it from then on in full screen portrait-sized (or rotated into landscape).
```

Hence it always killed and restarted my app.